# textview multiline problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am having two textviews in my linear layout i am facing the below visibility there

```
Hi    asdf asdf asdf asdf
      asdf asdf asdf asdf
      asdf asdf asdf asdf
      asdf asdf asdf asdf
```

here "Hi" is one textview and "asdf..." is one textview. But i want the visibility like below

```
Hi    asdf asdf asdf asdf
asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
asdf asdf
```

So the second textview should start from the starting of the parent layout and not after the end of first textview. Any suggestions would be really helpful in my learning of android?

Answer (score 0):

Please append both textview value and then display in third textview so may be solved your visibility like that.

Comment: am facing this problem because "Hi" should not be clickable but "asdf.." should be clickable. So i think both should be in different textviews.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good Idea but worth trying, try using the below xml with the help of Framelayout you can achieve this, Also add your Idea to improve it, Here just append some space for the text in second text view to make it look apart from first text view.

```
<FrameLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">    
<TextView 
     android:id="@+id/ID1"
     android:text="HI"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#00529b">
     </TextView>
<TextView 
     android:id="@+id/ID2"
     android:text="      Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello "  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" >
     </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thnx this helped and resolved the problem but i think this is not ideal solution. We need to know the length of the first textview and change the spaces for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can salve this set the text as HTML in your TextView.

for ex

`myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>")`

There are some more utility classes available to do linking and much more

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

Check example for this 
http://jtomlinson.blogspot.com/2010/03/textview-and-html.html

Comment: Yeah this is also one sort of solution but it will not resolve my problem because i want to user the clickable text to open some new activity and not URL. Is it possible to open an activity through linkify? Any suggestions would be really helpful in my learning..